# How to monitor custom metadata usage

Tags: limits, custom-metadata, usagemetrics

We have started to get "The custom metadata organization limit was reached" errors when deploying changes that include new custom metadata records.

I understand [what the limit is, and how it's calculated](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131874). Under Setup > Custom Metadata Types, I can also see there is a column, "Record Size", that tells me how big an individual record is.

What I can't quickly see is how many records exist from each type. There are over 50 different custom metadata types in my org, so querying each type one by one is burdensome. Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this with an Execute Anonymous script:

```java
for (String key : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().keySet()) {
    if (key.contains('__mdt')) {
        Integer recordCount = Database.countQuery('SELECT COUNT() FROM ' + key);
        System.debug(key + ': ' + recordCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: As a quick note for others, this is one of the rare times where it is ok to query inside of a loop (i.e. when you know for a fact that you'll use less than 100 queries, and that you don't need to conserve queries for other code).